# Knockout JS binding on computed observable does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js, typescript

I am trying to add a new field to an asp.net MVC 5 website popup screen that uses Entity Framework 6 code first, Typescript and Knockout JS for databinding.  I did not write this website.  I have been making changes to it for a few months.  The original programmer is no longer with the company.  I have never worked with these technologies previously.

The new field is the result of a web service call.  The web method does return results.  However, the value is not displayed on the screen.  I script runs and displays all the other data.  The deferred call to the web service returns after the page displays.  I will provide the markup and view model code.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Below is the computed property that the HTML is bound to:

```
this.PredictedValue = ko.pureComputed(() => {
                var age = "";
                var race = "";
                var height = "";
                var studyId = this.Session().Study.PftCentralStudyId();
                var predictedSetName;
                var predictedSetId;
                var gender;
                if (this.StudyTestParameter().HasPredictedValues() == true) {
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.Session().Study.StudyTestTypePredictedSets(),(item: Bll.TestTypePredictedSetVm) => {
                        if (String(item.TestType().Name()) == this.StudyTestParameter().TestType().Name())
                            predictedSetId = item.PredictedSetId();
                    });
                    if (predictedSetId == 0) {
                        return "";
                    }
                    else {
                        var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.Session().PftCentralStudyPredictedSets(),(item: Bll.PftCentralPredictedSetsVm) => {
                            return String(item.Id) == String(predictedSetId)
                        });
                        predictedSetName = match.Name;
                        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.Session().SessionValues(),(item: SessionValueVm) => {
                            if (String(item.StudySessionParameter().Name()) == "Age")
                                age = String(item.RecordedValue());
                        });
                        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.Session().SessionValues(),(item: SessionValueVm) => {
                            if (String(item.StudySessionParameter().Name()) == "Race")
                                race = String(item.RecordedValue());
                        });
                        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.Session().SessionValues(),(item: SessionValueVm) => {
                            if (String(item.StudySessionParameter().Name()) == "Height")
                                height = String(item.RecordedValue());
                        });
                        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.Session().SessionValues(),(item: SessionValueVm) => {
                            if (String(item.StudySessionParameter().Name()) == "Sex")
                                gender = String(item.RecordedValue());
                        });
                        var promise = this.Session().CalculatePredicted(age, race, gender, height, String(this.StudyTestParameter().PftCentralStudyParameterId()), predictedSetName, studyId);
                        promise.done((data: string) => {
                            return data
                        });
                    }
                }
                else
                    return "";
            });

CalculatePredicted = (age: string, race: string, gender: string, height: string, studySessionParameterId: string, predictedSetName: string, studyId: number) => {

            var deferred = $.Deferred();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Workflows/CalculatePredicted",
                cache: false,
                data: { age: age, ethnicity: race, gender: gender, height: height, studySessionParameterId: studySessionParameterId, testTypePredictedSetName: predictedSetName, studyId: studyId },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8"
            }).done(data => {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).fail((jqXHR) => {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                deferred.reject();
            });
            return deferred;
        }
```

Below is the HTML.

```
<div>
                                        Test Values:
                                        <table class="width100pct gridtable">
                                            <tbody data-bind="foreach: TestValues">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td data-bind="text: StudyTestParameter().Name"></td>
                                                <td data-bind="text: RecordedValue"></td>
                                                <td data-bind="text: ATSBestValue"></td>
                                                <td data-bind="text: PredictedValue"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your promise object can't return for your computed. By the time the promise is done, the computed has long returned 'undefined'. That is the nature of async calls. Consider setting a different observable within the promise.done() function and bind to that new field in the UI instead; the computed function will still trigger if the underlying fields change.

Comment: If that was the problem, wouldn't the view eventually update once the promise is returned and the computed value changes? I've used computed variables that contain asynch calls many times with no issue..

Comment: you can't have a promise return the value for a computed, that's basic async stuff. You'd have to update another observable within the promise that the UI ties to instead.

Comment: I tried it and the results did not change.  I defined a new class property "FinalPredictedValue = ko.observable();"  I changed the other method as: var promise = this.Session().CalculatePredicted(age, race, gender, height, String(this.StudyTestParameter().PftCentralStudyParameterId()), predictedSetName, studyId);
                        promise.done((data: string) => {
                            this.FinalPredictedValue(ko.observable(data));
                        });

Comment: Would a custom binding be worth trying?  I have never used one before.

Comment: @Edward you can't use `this` like that to set the property, it won't be the right context.

Comment: I am new to knockout js.  How would I set a different observable within the promise.done() function and bind to that new field in the UI?  The observable would have to be a property of the ViewModel class.